# Select given ranges of indexes from source array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I want to create an array with the taken indexes of an array. Let's suppose I have an array like this:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
```

And the result I get from my query looks like:

[image]

Which means that places `1`, `3, 4` (`LengthUnit` = 2)and `7` are busy (already taken). So, the array now would look like:

```
| T | 2 | T | T | 5 | 6 | T | 8 | 9 | 10 |
```

Where, `T` stands for taken.

How can I create two arrays of integers using the result from query which would look like:

```
int[] taken = { 1, 3, 4, 7 };
int[] notTaken = { 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10 };
```

Comment: Loop over the query result and Skip() and Take() the appropriate indices? What have you tried?

Comment: start Unit has `1, 3, 7 ` howz `4` is taken?

Comment: @yogi this isn't explained in the question, but given LengthUnit for 3 is 2, I assume the OP wants to take 2 records starting from 3.

Comment: @CodeCaster You are right

Comment: @yogi 2 is the length unit starting from the start unit. So, 3,4 are taken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Enumerable.Range` proofs to be useful in this case:

```
Dictionary<int, int> startAndLength = new Dictionary<int, int>()
                                      { { 1, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 7, 1 } };

int[] taken = startAndLength
              .SelectMany(kvp => Enumerable.Range(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)).ToArray();

int[] notTaken = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Except(taken).ToArray();
```

Start creating a set of starts and lengths, then determine the taken items using `Enumerable.Range`. Then use `Enumerable.Range` again to determine the items *not* taken.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Enumerable.Range` to create the collection of items you want. Then use `Except` to get the others.

```
List<int> values = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

List<Tuple<int, int>> ranges = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
{
    new Tuple<int, int>(1,1),
    new Tuple<int, int>(3,2),
    new Tuple<int, int>(7,1),
};

var t = ranges.SelectMany(range => Enumerable.Range(range.Item1, range.Item2)).ToList();

// Here I decide to use Intersect instead of just having t for the case 
// where you requested a range that doesn't exist
var taken = values.Intersect(t).ToArray();
var notTaken = values.Except(taken).ToList();
```

In the case that you want the values and that they **aren't sequential** like in the example then instead: create a collection of all desired indexes and then get all items of those indexes:

```
var indexes = ranges.SelectMany(range => Enumerable.Range(range.Item1, range.Item2)).Select(item => item - 1).ToList();

var taken = values.Where((item, index) => indexes.Contains(index)).ToList();
var notTaken = values.Where((item, index) => !indexes.Contains(index)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

A little Linq will get you a long way:

```
public class QueryResult
{
    public int StartUnit { get; set; }
    public int LengthUnit { get; set; }
}

var input = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

var queryResult = new QueryResult[]
{
    new QueryResult { StartUnit = 1, LengthUnit = 1 },
    new QueryResult { StartUnit = 3, LengthUnit = 2 },
    new QueryResult { StartUnit = 7, LengthUnit = 1 },
};

var taken = new List<int>();

taken.AddRange(queryResult.SelectMany(q => (input.Skip(q.StartUnit - 1).Take(q.LengthUnit))));

Console.WriteLine("Taken: {0}", string.Join(",", taken));

var notTaken = input.Except(taken);

Console.WriteLine("Not taken: {0}", string.Join(",", notTaken));
```

Using `SelectMany()`, `Skip()` and `Take()`, you can select the ranges that you wish to include. Using `Except()` you can then get the items not taken.

Note that this will perform horribly, as it iterates the collections way too many times. It also assumes that the `StartUnit` actually denotes an (index + 1) in the input collection, not a value.

If you don't actually want to look at the input array, and the values are always contiguous (i.e. no holes in the input), you can use `Enumerable.Range()` to generate the requested ranges:

```
taken.AddRange(queryResult.SelectMany(q => Enumerable.Range(q.StartUnit, q.LengthUnit)));
```

And generate the full range for the `Except()` to exclude from:

```
var notTaken = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Except(taken);
```

And of course if you want the output to actually be arrays, do a call to `ToArray()` here and there.

Comment: @Tim but it assumes that the input is always contiguous.